# Why doesn't D-Link router's DNS return local hostnames?

Tags: router, dns, hostname

I own a D-Link DIR-600.  You can see part of its configuration here:

[image: D-Link configuration screenshot]

As you can see, I set two fixed hostnames, "wilson", and "sheldon".  However, if I try to access them by name, no matter from which of my computers in my LAN, no matter whether Ubuntu/Windows, this doesn't work:

```
$ nslookup wilson
Server:     192.168.178.1
Address:    192.168.178.1#53

** server can't find wilson: NXDOMAIN

$ nslookup wilson.local
Server:     192.168.178.1
Address:    192.168.178.1#53

** server can't find wilson.local: NXDOMAIN

$ nslookup stackexchange.com
Server:     192.168.178.1
Address:    192.168.178.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   stackexchange.com
Address: 69.59.197.21
```

Is there a way to get these hostnames, besides adding them to /etc/hosts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Linux on both matchines, try `getent hosts wilson.local`, or simply `ping wilson.local`.  This assumes you already have avahi-daemon and nss-mdns installed, which is usually the case.

Specific DNS tools like nslookup and dig don't automatically support .local over MDNS (multicast DNS).  They bypass the standard C library for name resolution, and don't integrate with avahi-daemon themselves.

I have also tried setting "search local" in /etc/resolv.conf / asking NetworkManager to use "local" as a local domain.  I.e. allowing `ping wilson` without the .local.  But it looks like nss-mdns doesn't implement it.

I don't have instructions for Windows.  The simplest way might be to use Bonjour from Apple.

That's the Apple-derived system that Linux adopted.  There's also a Windows-based alternative.  Linux can integrate into it using the "winbind" daemon from samba.  I don't have instructions for that either :).

---

I don't think my Netgear DG834 returns local DNS names either.  Interestingly, I think they could if they wanted to.  My router and others uses dnsmasq, and the *default* dnsmasq configuration already returns local DNS names.  I've tested this myself - I run dnsmasq on a Linux server, and disable/ignore my router's DHCP/DNS services.

Comment: ping, ssh, with or without .local, all this don't work.  For the time being, I added the hostnames to /etc/hosts.  They have fixed IPs anyway.  Thanks for the info about your Netgear device.  Where does the default dnsmasq get all the hostnames of the LAN from?

Comment: The hostnames are provided in their DHCP requests.

Comment: Update: hostnames _can_ be provided in DHCP requests, but may not be.  A recent version of Windows does it.  Recent NetworkManager does it (Ubuntu, debian unstable, but seemingly NOT debian 6.0).  It's not done on non-NetworkManager setups on debian 6.0 either (I haven't tested others).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  Actually, I was just confused because I thought the router got the local names from the computers.  But obviously, it is the other way round.  Be that as it may, both my D-Link and your Netgear don't return the hostnames in DNS lookups, and this is the problem.